# Ability to send multiple objects into http post request in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, http, post

I need to make a post request for 5000-10000 objects every time I run my program. I could send a separate post request for each object but that has negative impacts on my programs performance. I would like to make one post request for all of the objects.

```
createObjects(obj: Object): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post<Object>(this.objUrl, { obj }).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

I tried sending an array of objects in the post request but instead of giving each individual object an id it gave the entire array of objects an id.

```
createObjects(obj: Object[]): Observable<Object[]> {
    return this.http.post<Object[]>(this.objUrl, { obj }).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is when I try to pass an array of objects it assigns one id to the whole array instead of assigning an Individual id to each element inside of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate all the objects in the array *manually*, then send the array by a single POST request.